# How to Display loggedin User Picture in a Content Editor WebPart

Tags: 2013, user-profile

I am trying to display loggedin users image on top of left hand side navigation where I would have a `div`. Before I do that I want to display same in Content Editor WebPart so that I can have more flexibility to make changes before I apply that in master page. I have following script to display other info regarding user but how do I display a picture?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
    document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title();
    document.getElementById('userEmail').innerHTML = currentUser.get_email();



}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>

<div>Current User: 
    <span id="userLoginName"></span></br>
</div>
<div>Username:
    <span id="userTitle"></span></br>
</div>
<div>Email:
    <span id="userEmail"></span></br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SP.UserProfiles.js to get the URL of the user like this:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
   var targetUser = "SomeDomain\\SomeUserName";
     // Get the current client context.
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
    // Get the properties to retrieve
    var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "PictureURL"];
    var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
    clientContext,
    targetUser,
    profilePropertyNames);
    // Get user profile properties for the target user
    userProfileProperties =peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
    // Load the UserProfilePropertiesForUser object.
    clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
    //Execute the Query
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

function onRequestSuccess() {
    document.getElementById("profilelink").href = userProfileProperties[1];;
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = userProfileProperties[0];
    if (userProfileProperties[1]!== null) {
        document.getElementById("Userprofileimage").src = userProfileProperties[1];
    }
}



// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    $get("Userprofileimage ").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

Comment: Ahmed thank you for you response, on var targetUser = "SomeDomain\\SomeUserName"; are we supposed to assign logged in users domain\username ?

Comment: This is what i did and it worked, but i have other javascripts loaded in the page too. Problem is only one javascript code works at a time. 

How should i resovle this, do you think it is because of ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProfileImage,'sp.js');